# Why doesn't my spreadsheet identify duplicate date/times?

Tags: excel

I am trying to identify duplicate date/times down to the second. I have a list of transactions, and column N has the date/time together in one box.

I have used both a formula and conditional formatting to try to identify the duplicates. Both methods do identify some duplicates. Both methods identify the same duplicates. But I can visually see that there are tons of duplicates that it is missing.

Here is an example of the cells I'm comparing to look for duplicates;

ApprovedDate
4/15/19 12:03

4/30/19 8:17

4/4/19 14:19

4/5/19 11:07

4/10/19 9:39

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00

4/12/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/22/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/22/19 9:00

4/22/19 9:00

4/22/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/22/19 9:00

4/22/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/22/19 9:00

4/22/19 9:00    Duplicated

4/24/19 15:16   Duplicated

4/25/19 9:00

4/25/19 9:00

4/30/19 9:00

4/30/19 9:00    Duplicated

The obvious answer for this list is seconds are different, that's why some aren't being marked as duplicates. So I changed the formatting to the following, and I can still visually see duplicates that aren't being counted as duplicates;

ApprovedDate
1045692:03:50

1046048:17:24

1045430:19:18

1045451:07:01

1045569:39:52

1045617:00:08

1045617:00:09

1045617:00:08

1045617:00:06

1045617:00:07   Duplicated

1045617:00:06

1045617:00:09

1045617:00:08

1045617:00:08

1045617:00:07   Duplicated

1045857:00:08   Duplicated

1045857:00:08

1045857:00:08

1045857:00:08   Duplicated

1045857:00:08

1045857:00:08   Duplicated

1045857:00:08

1045857:00:08   Duplicated

1045911:16:35   Duplicated

1045929:00:10

1045929:00:10

1046049:00:22

1046049:00:23   Duplicated

The formula I have tried so far is;

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(N$2:N$50000,N22)>1,"Duplicated","")
```

I need to find all duplicate date/time entries on this spreadsheet so that I can audit items that occurred at the exact same time, down to the second.

Comment: Changing the format doesn't change the underlying value. Perhaps create a helper column and strip off the seconds in it.

Comment: Dates are **integer** numbers and hours,minutes and seconds are the **decimal** part. You should round values to same number of decimals first, before searching for duplicates. As @BigBen said before, changing the cell's format does not change the real value of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your formula to a COUNTIFS with two criteria in order to capture the right range of hours/minutes only:

`=IF(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$50000,">="&ROUNDDOWN(N2*24*60,0)/24/60,$N$2:$N$20000,"<="&(1+ROUNDDOWN(N2*24*60,0))/24/60)>1,"Duplicated","")`

What this does is multiply the date/time value by 24 and 60 to convert it to minutes, then rounds it down. After that, multiply it by 24 and 60 again to get a real date/time value for comparison. For the upper limit, I've added 1.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thank you very much! One quick question, is there a way to not have to name the end of the range? So that regardless of how many rows there are it will look all the way to the bottom?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that, but the the best way is to have your data in a proper Table (insert -> table) then you can refer to the columns by their names instead of a range.